# It should be used **with** in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, writing-style, formality, writing-advice

Should be used **with** in this paragraph to indicate the contribution that she could do by studying a specific master's program?

Using water is necessary but it needs to be done carefully to avoid draining it all, which she can contribute **with** by adding the insights this master's program provides to her training as an ecologist to find sustainable alternatives of use

Comment: There are other problems with your paragraph, but no, you contribute _to_ something, not _with_ it.

Comment: Firstly, pepo, I think you mean "Should **with** be used in this paragraph?". The trouble is that it's not a well-formed question and "《Something》 should be used with 《something else》" is a standard expression in English meaning that one thing should be used in combination with another. For instance "Soap should be used with water". Also the paragraph you quote is very unclear. Did you see it somewhere or have you written it?

Comment: @KateBunting, which do you think are the other problems with the paragraph?

Comment: @BoldBen the question and paragraph were edited.

Comment: The main problem is that too much information is being packed into one sentence. Breaking it down into two or three separate sentences may improve the clarity.

Comment: This forum is not supposed to provide a proof-reading service, but  I agree with @Shoe's suggestion of breaking your paragraph into shorter sentences. For one thing, it's not clear what _which_ refers to.

Comment: If this is supposed to be advertising for a masters course in ecology, which it seems to be, you would do better to write it in your own language and have it translated by a native English speaker who knows your language rather than trying to write it in English yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

One contributes *to* by adding the insights, or she can contribute to *with* the insights she may add.